# How do I increase the "primary key" autoincrement number?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a column that is primary key / auto increment.

As more records are created, of course the number increments.

Right now, if a record is inserted, it will have a primary_key of "10".

How can I increase that number to "200"?

In other words, I want the primary key to have 200, 201, 202 from now on....instead of 11, 12, 13.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=200;
```

The MySql documentation mentions this in the [ALTER TABLE syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/alter-table.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the new value of your auto-increment using:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to, but this should work:

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;

Answer (score 1):

As stated in mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) (which you should read in case of doubt :) )

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;
```

Answer (score 1):

after the alteration of the table, the newly inserted record starts on 200.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;
```